# ESlint Airbnb Config Complains about Quotes

Tags: ecmascript-6, atom-editor, eslint

I'm working with Airbnb's linting rules, which notably has this line in it:

`"react/jsx-quotes": 1,`

All other rules seem to be functioning as expected. Yet, when I use a single quote for `'use strict;'` I'm flashed with a warning sign:

[image]

(Here's a [link](https://gist.github.com/hendrikswan/2153ae77f1496d2b40aa) to the entire eslint file).

What could be issue with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule react/jsx-quotes was deprecated in Sept 2015. Originally it was in the airbnb project, however quotes, being such an essential linting rule got moved to the main eslint project as jsx-quotes; and airbnb removed react/jsx-quotes rule in their later versions.

https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-quotes.md